# How to enter a range of Work days in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to set a task in which I say

"My task starts on XX, May 2011 and ends after 14 work days"

How do I automatically put this date range in an Excel sheet?

So, can I put something like:

```
A1Cell: 2 May 2011
A2Cell: =$A1+1 (should be a WorkDay) 
A3Cell: =$A2+1 (should be a WorkDay)
A4Cell: =$A3+1 (should be a WorkDay)
A5Cell: =$A4+1 (should be a WorkDay)
A6Cell: =$A5+1 (should be a WorkDay, as this is Saturday, it should automatically take it as the next workday)
```

Can something like the above be achieved in Excel? Or if there is a VBA code available for it?

What I could get was something like:

```
=IF($A5=(WORKDAY($A5,0)),$A5+1,$A5+3)
```

But it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the formula, adding the number of working days (column A) to today

```
=WORKDAY(TODAY(),A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Also try the [WORKDAY.INTL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/starter-help/workday-intl-function-HA010354380.aspx) function (if you are in excel2010). Allows you to pick which days are weekends and set specific holidays